# Magento third party library does not work

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-gateway, ce-1.9.2.3

Installed module : https://github.com/E-ComProcessing/magento-ce-ecp-plugin
generate below system.log:

```
2016-11-21T09:04:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/includes/src/Genesis\Genesis.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-11-21T09:04:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/includes/src/Genesis\Genesis.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/includes/src:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php')  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-11-21T09:04:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/includes/src/Genesis\Genesis.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-11-21T09:04:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/includes/src/Genesis\Genesis.php' for inclusion (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/includes/src:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php')  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
```

Can any one suggest me what is the directory structure of the third party codes?

how can i debug this?

Comment: can you share the process to install the module that you followed

Comment: installed by directory structure of magneto.

Comment: You can look module link directory just copy paste in root of magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem.
Perhaps there is a problem loading Gateway Client Library using composer.
Replace the function initLibrary in the DataHelper Class:

```
app/code/community/EComProcessing/Genesis/Helper/Data.php
public function initLibrary()
    {
        // Mitigate PHP Bug #52339, as Magento already registers their AutoLoader
        if (!class_exists('\Genesis\Genesis', false)) {
             $genesisAutoLoadParams = array(
                'magento_root'                       => MAGENTO_ROOT,
                'integrated_genesis_lib_auto_loader' => Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . DS . 'Genesis' . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php',
                'genesis_composer_dir'               => 'genesisgateway',
                'check_genesis_lib_version'          => '1',
                'required_genesis_lib_version'       => ">= 1.4"
             );

             $genesisAutoLoadVarienObj = new Varien_Object($genesisAutoLoadParams);

             /* This Event will be handled from Observer EComProcessing_Genesis_Observer_GenesisAutoLoader (defined in etc/config.xml) */
             Mage::dispatchEvent('ecomprocessing_genesis_init_library', array('genesis_auto_load_params' => $genesisAutoLoadVarienObj));
        }        
    }
```

with this one

```
public function initLibrary()
    {
        if (!class_exists('\Genesis\Genesis', false)) {
            include Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . DS . 'Genesis' . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like compilation is enabled in your site. Please disable it or re-compile through `System -> Tools -> Compilation` and remove all your cache. Then try again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Compiler Status : Disabled,
Cache Status : Disabled,
Cache : Clear,
index : Done,
still getting log report.

Comment: It looks like they are using some external packages which classes are incompatable in Magento. Best thing you can do here is, contact developers of that extension.